# Connecting a database on Oracle server from Go without any client on the go side

Tags: oracle, go

I checked out the go connectors available: go-oci8 and goracle, they need oracle client installed on the go side, is there any way to connect to oracle without the need of these clients?My go version is 1.7, I came across go-goracle/goracle but it requires minimum go 1.9
 I am getting this error:

```
    go get gopkg.in/goracle.v2
    # gopkg.in/goracle.v2
    .go/src/gopkg.in/goracle.v2/orahlp.go:271: undefined: driver.Pinger
```

Please can anyone suggest anything which works with go version 1.7 without the client installed.
 Regards,
 Sheetal

Comment: You cannot connect to Oracle from _anything_ without an Oracle client installed.

Comment: Do you want a stateful, always on connection? Or could you rely on https calls to a mid tier?

Comment: I dont need a always on connection, the connection should be established only when there is a request, I dont expect the incoming traffic to be more than 1 req per min.